# How to pass unknow model as parameter in Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

On the method below, "Account" is a class (model). Is it possible to pass it as a parameter, such as GetDisplayName(object model, string col) so that the method can be called with different models?

```
 protected string GetDisplayName(string col)
        {
            var name = "";
            try
            {
                MemberInfo property = typeof(Account).GetProperty(col);
                var dd = property.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DisplayAttribute)) as DisplayAttribute;
                if (dd != null)
                {
                    name = Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(dd.Name);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                name = "label not found";
            }
            return name;
        }
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. If the method accepts `object`, you can pass anything to it. But maybe use generics, inheritance or an interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You certainly could, just use `model.GetType()` instead of `typeof(Account)`:

```cs
 protected string GetDisplayName(object model, string col)
 {
    var name = "";
    try
    {
        MemberInfo property = model.GetType().GetProperty(col);
        var dd = property.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DisplayAttribute)) as DisplayAttribute;
        if (dd != null)
        {
            name = Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(dd.Name);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        name = "label not found";
    }
    return name;
}
```

However, I would advise against that, a cleaner way to implement this is to have all models that need to generate a display name implement an interface:

```cs
public interface IHasDisplayName
{
  string GetDisplayName();
}
```

Comment: Agreed much cleaner approach, alternatively they can derive from the same base

Answer (score 3):

make it generic

```
protected string GetDisplayName<T>(string col) where T:class
        {
            var name = "";
            try
            {
                MemberInfo property = typeof(T).GetProperty(col);
                var dd = property.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DisplayAttribute)) as DisplayAttribute;
                if (dd != null)
                {
                    name = Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(dd.Name);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                name = "label not found";
            }
            return name;
        }
```